# Vector fields pointing from one fiber to another - Notation

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

Let $(P,M,\pi)$ be a Principal $G$ bundle.

I am quoting following lines from the book Modern Differential geometry for Physicists by C J Isham.

> The basic idea of parallel transport/covariant differentiation is to compare points in neighbouring fibers ina way that is not dependent on any particular local bundle trivialisation. This suggests looking for vector fields that point from one fiber to another.

I do not understand why does idea of comparing fibers of two nearby points should suggest looking for some vector fields. It is not clear what does it mean to say vector field that points from one fiber to another.

I thought I might understand if I go further but still it is not clear.

In search of some vector fields (which is not clear at this point what kind of vector fields they are) he defines vector field $X^A$ on $P$ given an element $A\in T_eG$. I am not defining it because definition is not relavent here. He then says with out proof that $$\pi_*\left( X^A_p\right)=0$$
I have checked this and it turns out to be true. Before saying this, he says

> How ever, the particular vector fields are not suitable for our purposes since they do not point from one fiber to another. On the contrary, the vectors $X^A_p$ are tangent to the fiber at $p\in P$ and hence they point along the fiber, rather than away from it. Technically, $X^A_p$ is said to be a vertical vector i.e., it belongs to the vertical subspace $V_pP$ of $T_pP$ defined by

$$V_pP= \left\{ \tau\in T_pP : \pi_*\tau=0\right\}$$ 
where $\pi$ is the projection map of the bundle.

I do not understand what does it mean to say vectors are tangent to the fibers or point along the fibers.

Comment: Do you know what it means for a vector to be tangent to a submanifold? Well, being tangent to fibers means precisely that.

Comment: I do not know what does it mean to say vector is tangent to a submanifold. Does it mean it is derivative of a curve at a point which lies entirely in the submanifold? @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: That is one possible definition, yes. If your confusion is about that, then essentally everything else in the question is irrelevant. I suggest you read up a bit more on manifolds, vector fields and so on before starting with connections on principal bundles!

Comment: I have spend quite some time on manifolds, vector fields. Can you suggest what exactly would I need to understand connections on principal bundle. I now need to know what does it mean to say vector is tangent to submanifold. Anything else do you suggest? @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez some reference would also be useful.

Comment: I would suggest before tackling connections on principal bundles, first consider Koszul connections on vector bundles, where the derivative is defined in terms of the familiar Newton quotient, and the need to relate adjacent fibers is very clear. Then consider the generalization to a general fiber bundle, the Ehresemann connection, and its associated connection form. Then consider how to make that definition $G$-equivariant for a principal bundle. A textbook which covers these which I liked is Michelson and Lawson's Spin Geometry, but different books will use different levels of abstraction...

Comment: and M&L are on the very abstract end. For a less abstract approach, perhaps a book for physicists like Nakahara? But it sounds like you already have one of those in Isham.

Comment: Actually, although I have never seen it presented this way, I guess a connection on a principal bundle _can_ be viewed in terms of a Newton quotient. Perhaps I can add this to my answer...

Comment: I looked in Michelson and Lawson today and I can't say it's a good choice for a first look at connections on principal bundles.

Comment: I would try with Koszul connections on vector bundles and then try to come back to connections on principal bundles as you have suggested @ziggurism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally a fiber bundle looks like a product. So to understand local statements about fiber bundles, it is enough to study a product. For example, a line bundle over a 1-manifold looks like the trivial bundle $\mathbb{R}^2\overset{\pi}{\to}\mathbb{R}$, a bundle whose total space is the product $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, whose base is $\mathbb{R},$ and projection $\text{proj}_2\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which has value $\text{proj}_2(x,y)=x$.

In this trivialization, a point in the base looks like $(3,0)$, a fiber looks like $\pi^{-1}(3)=3\times\mathbb{R}=\{(3,y)\colon y\in\mathbb{R}\}.$  A vertical vector looks like $e_y=\partial_y$, and this vector is tangent to the fiber $\pi^{-1}(3).$ A vector pointing to an adjacent fiber may look like $e_x=\partial_x$ or $e_x+e_y=\partial_x+\partial_y$. Anything which is not vertical. The subbundle of vertical vectors is the set of all vectors $V(\mathbb{R}^2)=\{f(x,y)\partial_y\}.$

Comment: @cello I added some clarification about the bundle structure of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. Hopefully it's clearer? Please feel free to ask if any aspect is not clear.

Comment: @cello, it is not a good idea to imply that an answer is not "very serious". Please do not do that.

Comment: I tried to give a very concrete answer using low-dimensional easy-to-visualize spaces, to make it understandable. I thought this was a benefit, not a flaw. But if this answer doesn't meet your needs, please clarify what you would like to see.

Comment: I take back my words which sounds like I am saying that the answer is not serious. I really do not mean like that. Reading my comment for third time makes me feel like it means that and I ask for an apologise to user ziggurism.

Comment: I will re-read your answer. It seems to be clear but I need some more time to really understand. I am sorry, I have gone completely blank now.

Comment: @cello Even if you don't like the answer, you may still get other answers that you will like better. Or other readers may still benefit from my answer. There is no need to delete the question. :(

Comment: I was going to edit my question. I am using my iPad now so it was difficult to edit. I thought I would do when I go to my office. Somehow, there is so much of misunderstanding.

Comment: @cello does that mean you still have questions?

Comment: No, Mariano suggested that something in my question is irrelevant. So, I thought of checking it once. As of now, I have just one question. Why would the  idea of  comparing points in neighbouring fibers in a way that is not dependent on any particular local bundle trivialisation suggests looking for vector fields that point from one fiber to another? Except that other things are clear.

Comment: @cello Fixing a horizontal subbundle, as it's called, gives a unique way to transport between fibers. That's what is meant by a vector pointing to a neighboring fiber; a tangent vector to the total space which is complementary to the vertical (tangent to fiber) vectors.

Comment: Oh, I see. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed incorrect to say a vector field along a fiber is pointing to another point on another fiber. Just like a a tangent vector at a point on a sphere isn't pointing to another point on the sphere; it isn't because it's in the tangent space. That said, one needs to create a a means to transport vectors, otherwise calculus on manifolds couldn't be done. That's why connection 1-forms exist (also why Lie derivatives exist).